# How link N php containers with 1 nginx container

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker, docker-compose

i´m moving my wordpress farm (10 installs) to docker architecture,
I want had one nginx container and run 10 php-fpm containers (mysql is on external server)
the php containers are named php_domainname, and also contain persistent storage
i want know how do this:
a)How pass domainname and containername to vhost conf file¿

b)when i start a php-fpm container
1) add a vhost.conf file into nginx confs folder
2) add volume (persistent storage) to nginx instance
3) restart nginx instance

All nginx-php dockers that i founded, has both process per instance, but i think that had 10+1 nginx is overloading the machine, and break the docker advantages
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel, this one has already been solved by [docker-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) which is also [available on docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use consul or like with service-autodiscovery. This means:

- you add a consul server to your stack
- you register all FPM servers as nodes
- you register every FPM-daemon as a service "fpm" in consul

For your nginx vhost conf, lets say located `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mywpfarm.conf` you use consul-template https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template to generate the config in a go-template were you use

```
upstream fpm {
  {{range service "fpm"}}
    server {{.Name}} {{.Address}}:{{.Port}};
  {{end}}
}
```

In your location when you forward .php based request to the FPM upstream, you now use the upstream above. This way nginx will load-balance through all available servers. If you shutdown one FPM host, the config changes automatically and the FPM upstream gets adjusted ( thats what consul-template is for, it watches for changes ) - so you can add new FPM services at any time and scale horizontally very easy